# Extract img src from cdata text in XML

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xmllint

I would like to extract img src value from an XML file.

Test input:

```
<ROOT>
   <ITEM>
      <DESCRIPTION><![CDATA[<p align="left" dir="ltr">
    <span lang="EN">lorem ipsum</span></p>
<p>
    some text</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" src="https://example.com/hello.jpg" /></p>
]]></DESCRIPTION>
    </ITEM>
</ROOT>
```

What would be the best way to do it? With XSLT or an XML parser, like xmllint?

Currently I am trying with xmllint:

```
xmllint --xpath '//ROOT/ITEM/DESCRIPTION/text()' input.xml | egrep -o 'src=".*(\.png|\.jpg)'
```

...but output is like:

```
src="https://example.com/hello.jpg
```

Sure I can remove `src="`, with tools like sed, but maybe there is a better and cleaner solution to extract links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dig deep with XPath 3 or XSLT 3 throwing in `parse-xml-fragment`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">    

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="ROOT/ITEM/DESCRIPTION/parse-xml-fragment(.)//img/@src"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEv7

Saxon 9.9 HE is available in .NET, Java and C/C++/Python versions to run/use XSLT 3.

If the CDATA contains HTML that is not well-formed X(HT)ML then you could use the HTML parser implemented by David Carlisle in XSLT 2 (https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:html-parser="data:,dpc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="ROOT/ITEM/DESCRIPTION/html-parser:htmlparse(., '', true())//img/@src"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEv7/1

Comment: If I run this XSLT on the example XML, it works, but if I run it on actual XML I get error: ```error at char 46 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 11 column 88 of stage-2.xslt:
  FODC0006: First argument to parse-xml-fragment() is not a well-formed and
  namespace-well-formed XML fragment. XML parser reported: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
  systemId: file:./stage-2.xslt; lineNumber: 2;```

Comment: ```columnNumber: 176; The entity "ndash" was referenced, but not declared.
First argument to parse-xml-fragment() is not a well-formed and namespace-well-formed XML fragment. XML parser reported: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:./stage-2.xslt; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 176; The entity "ndash" was referenced, but not declared.```

Comment: Weird, I am running Saxon-HE 9.8.0.8J from Saxonica. Input XML does not ahve problem, at least If I open it in a browser, I don't get any error.

Comment: Well, we can't write code against input you don't show in your question but the error message clearly indicates that the CDATA section content I tried to parse with `parse-xml-fragment` is not a well-formed fragment as it seems to reference an entity like `ndash` which HTML parsers know but not XML parsers unless there is a DTD. So `parse-xml-fragment` can't parse that content, you will probably need an HTML parser to feed that CDATA section content to, Saxon PE and EE have an extension for that, HE not. You could use David Carlisle's HTML parser done in pure XSLT 2.

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEv7/2 has an example with an entity reference that the HTML parser seems to parse fine.

Comment: This is great, it is possible to generate new line in the output instead of spaces?

Comment: @BélaNem, sure, use `<xsl:value-of select="ROOT/ITEM/DESCRIPTION/html-parser:htmlparse(., '', true())//img/@src" separator="&#10;"/>` (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEv7/3).

Answer (score 1):

If your CDATA section would be well-formed XML if it wasn't in a CDATA section, you could pipe the output of xmllint to xmllint so the CDATA is parsed as XML.

In your specific example, you have to wrap the output in another element (`x` in example) to make it well-formed.

Example...

```
xmllint --xpath 'concat("<x>",string(//ROOT/ITEM/DESCRIPTION),"</x>")' input.xml | xmllint --xpath 'string(//img/@src)' -
```

Output...

```
https://example.com/hello.jpg
```

Comment: @BélaNem - Yes if there is more than one `img` element, it will only output the src value of the first (because xmllint uses xpath 1.0). You could probably switch to xmlstarlet and iterate over each `img`. If I have time later, I'll add an example.